# $\frac{n}{n!} = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}$? true for confined $n$?

Tags: calculus

I'm attempting to derive that $\frac{d}{dx}\sin{x} = \cos{x}$, and I have in priori that $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$, so then $e^{kx} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^nx^n}{n!}$ (all this in order to differentiate by distributing the derivative over $\frac{e^{ix}}{2i} - \frac{e^{-ix}}{2i}$), furthermore I am trying to differentiate this $e^{kx}$ and I proceed as follows:

$$
 \begin{equation}
  \tag{1} \frac{d}{dx}e^{kx} = \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^nx^n}{n!} 
 \end{equation}
$$
$$
 \begin{equation}
  \tag{2}\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^nx^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{k^nx^n}{n!}  
 \end{equation}
$$
$$
 \begin{equation}
  \tag{3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{k^nx^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{nk^nx^{n-1}}{n!}
 \end{equation}
$$

Then, recalling that $n!$ is recursively defined as $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(...)(1): n \geq 0, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \cup \{0\}$, given $\frac{nk}{n!} = \frac{nk}{n(n-1)(n-2)(...)(1)}$, the factor $n$ divides itself and we get $\frac{k}{(n-1)(n-2)(...)(1)} = \frac{k}{(n-1)!}$ per the definition of my factorial.

$$
 \begin{equation}
  \tag{4} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{nk^nx^{n-1}}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^nx^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}
 \end{equation}
$$

But, evidently, when $n=0$ then we have the case of $(-1)!$ in the denominator, which is undefined according to my definition; and according to Wolfram ($\Gamma(0)$) it's $\bar{\infty}$.

Where have I gone wrong in my derivation?

Comment: You can't always write ${n \over n!} = {1 \over (n-1)!}$ . It is only valid for $n \ge 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of $n!$ as $n(n-1)\cdots1$ is not a recursive definition.

Concerning your main question, yes, $(-1)!$ is undefined. On the other hand, $\frac n{n!}=0$ when $n=0$. So\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{nk^nx^{n-1}}{n!}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nk^nx^{n-1}}{n!}\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{k^nx^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Note that the first term on the LHS of (4) is zero ($n$ appears as a factor in the numerator). So your first index on the LHS should be $1$, and then this problem goes away.

The real problem is that the statement $$\frac{n}{n!}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$$
is only true for integers $n\geq 1$, because if you allow $n=0$ you would be claiming $0/0=1$, which is false.